# While loops with timer in c++

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to create a while loop that when either the string condition or the timer condition is met, the program will break out of the loop and print out the desired output. And when printing out the desired output, the output will contain the time difference from before and after comparing the answer.

But the loop doesn't run the way i expects it to. So can anyone help me figure out where is the problem with this piece of code?

Below is my code:

```
void startGame(time_t cd,int gl){
    string guessWord;
    time_t start, end, diff,timeLeft;

    cout << "Scrambled word is " << randomizeWord(gl) << endl;

    while (timeLeft != cd || guessWord.compare(originalWord) == 0)
    {
        start = time(0);
        cout << "You have " << cd << " seconds to guess." << endl;
        cout << "Enter guess : ";
        cin >> guessWord;
        end = time(0);
        diff = end - start;
        //total_time = total_time + diff;
        timeLeft = cd - diff;

        if(guessWord.compare(originalWord) != 0)
        {
            cout << "WRONG! Attempt ... You have " << timeLeft << "seconds left... Try Again" << endl;
            cout << "Enter guess : ";
            cin >> guessWord;             
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "You are CORRECT! "<< timeLeft <<" seconds left. Your timing is "<< diff <<" seconds." << endl;            
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change to: `timeLeft >= cd `

Comment: Don't do `guessWord.compare(...)` twice, one in the loop body and one in the loop condition. Use a "succeeded" variable. If the one in the loop body succeeds, set that variable to true. In the loop condition, use `!succeeded`. The time condition of the loop should be written more clearly, too - I didn't understand it after looking at it for five seconds, and that is a red sign for loop conditions. Also, `cd` is a poor choice for a parameter name.

Comment: @JoshGreifer Thanks I did that. But my problem still persists. I enter a wrong answer the 1st time and the program is supposed to continue prompting me for the answer. Then I enter the wrong answer 2nd time, it justs breaks the loop.

Comment: @Joel You need to debug your code. If it's not clear to you what's going on, use trace messages to help you.

Comment: @DanielDaranas by loop body u refering to the 'while' loop and loop condition u refering to the 'if-else' statement?

Comment: For starters, you might initialize `timeLeft` _before_ the `while`.  As written, you have undefined behavior.

Comment: @Joel The loop body are all the lines contained between `while (timeLeft != cd || guessWord.compare(originalWord) == 0)` and the `}` that closes the while.

Comment: Oh, and as @James says you should always, always, _always_ initialize your variables. You should never, _ever_ work with an uninitialized variable.

Answer (score 5):

#### Condition explanation

Change your loop condition too:

```
while ((timeLeft <= cd) && (guessWord.compare(originalWord) != 0))
```

You will break out if either of the conditions fail. This is because the result of the `&&` is false if either condition fails. So this will continue while `a)` You have time left and `b)` you have not guessed the word. Yur use of `||` will make the loop continue while either is true (thus both have to fail for the loop to exit).

`Note`: I personally think extra braces `()` are nice hear to make the expression more human readable. For an inexperienced programmer, they will not need to guess(look up) at the order of precedence

#### Time Left Calculation:

```
time_t start    = time(0);  // Make the start time absolute and outside the loop.
                            // Note: Use one line per variable declaration and initialize.
int    timeLeft = cd;       // timeLeft is a relative value that can be negative => `int`

// Notice I adjust timeLeft because of new definition.
while ((timeLeft > 0) && (guessWord.compare(originalWord) != 0))
{
    time_t end       = time(0);
    time_t timeTaken = end-start;        // Total time taken so Far.
    timeLeft         = cd - timeTaken;   // Time left is thus.
```

Comment: I'm not against extra braces in general, but there are a few basic priorities which every programmer should know: */% before +-, and comparison before logical and/or.  And too many parentheses confuses more than it helps.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Sure. I can agree in principle. I would not go so far as to say `confuses` but maybe looks ugly and thus harder to read. You have to balance the two and the situation and for big expression break them into multiple smaller expressions with intermediate well named variables.

Answer (score 0):

Your Starting time and end time both are time(0) that could be the problem.

```
    start = time(0);
    ..
    end = time(0);
```

Comment: The ctime [time()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/) function doesn't work that way. When you execute `time(0)` you are simply supplying a null pointer instead of a `time_t*`. This will result in getting the current time before and after, which I believe is what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: ya, but he was putting both of them in the same loop which cause the problem

Comment: That isn't what's causing the problem but it might be a bad implementation choice.

Answer (score 0):

As @JoshGreifer said, you need to first change `timeLeft != cd` to `timeLeft > cd` (or `>=`, although I would go with the former).

Additionally, before addressing your bug, I can see an issue with your program in that if the user takes a long time and `diff > cd`, then `timeLeft` will be negative. It will still allow the user another guess because the `if(guessWord.compare(originalWord) != 0)` condition is still met.

In your while loop, you are checking `guessWord.compare(originalWord) == 0` before a guess has been made (but it's fine because it's null). You are also checking `timeLeft != cd` before `timeLeft` has been initialized.

I don't see where you are initializing `originalWord`, please post the relevant code. **Is it a global variable?** If so, this might be the source of your error.

Answer (score 0):

---

Hey guys, its working now after making few changes to it so please take a look at my answer and tell me if there is anything more i should change to the logic or the way I code my program. So i can learn to code programmes in the future the right way.

Below is the new code:

```
void startGame(time_t countDown,int gl){
//bool succeeded = false;
string guessWord;
time_t start, end, timeTaken;
int timeLeft = countDown;

cout << "Scrambled word is " << randomizeWord(gl) << endl;
start = time(0);//start the time once word is given
//timeLeft refers to the amt of time input by user
cout << "You have " << timeLeft << " seconds to guess." << endl;
cout << "Enter guess : ";
cin >> guessWord;
//the program stopped running after changing '||' to '&&' operator
//so meaning the condition is wrong
//so i changed it back to '||'
while ((timeLeft > 0) || (guessWord.compare(originalWord) == 0))
{
    end = time(0);//takes in the time at the moment user inputs
    timeTaken = end - start;//calculate the amt of time taken by user to input
    timeLeft = countDown - timeTaken;//calculate the amt of time left from the user input of time

    //check whether input by user is the same as the original word from the program
    if(guessWord.compare(originalWord) != 0)
    {
        cout << "WRONG! Attempt ... You have " << timeLeft << "seconds left... Try Again" << endl;
        cout << "Enter guess : ";
        cin >> guessWord;             
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "You are CORRECT! "<< timeLeft <<" seconds left. Your timing is "<< timeTaken <<" seconds." << endl;            
        break;
    }
}
```

}